# Maximum number of Parameter Hints in IntelliJ/PhpStorm

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm-2017.2

Is it possible to change the maximum number of Parameters Hints in IntelliJ?

For example:

[image: After 25 Parameter hints I get an inspection.]
After 25 Parameter hints I get an inspection.

Is there any configuration to increase the number?

Comment: More likely, there is no such a feature try to ask for it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: @Russiancold This is the answer I expected. :( Thanks.